# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error occured when repeat calling of a function

Tags: java, swing, out-of-memory

Hi i got an error when calling a button function repeatedly

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error occured when repeat calling of a function
or repeat calling of a button

**Here  is the function code**

```
    static java.util.List<Book>books=ServiceFactory.getBookServiceImpl().findAllBook();

    JTable getTable() {
    String[] cols = {"No", "Call No", "Title", "Category",
    "Author", "Publisher", "Price",
    "Donar", "Remarks"};
    Object[][] data = new Object[books.size()][200000];

    //Create same data for the table.
    int i=0;
    for (Book book:books) {
    data[i][0] = i+1;
    data[i][1] = book.getCallNo();
    data[i][2] = book.getName();
    data[i][3] = book.getCategory_id().getName();
    data[i][4] = book.getAuthor();
    data[i][5] = book.getPublisher();
    data[i][6] = book.getPrice();
    data[i][7] = book.getFrom();
    data[i][8] = book.getRemark();

    i++;
    }



DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols) {
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
return false;
}
};
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

**Here is the function that perform button calling**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource()==btnBook){
new BookReport().getReport();


}

}
```

**Here is the error**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Vector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Vector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.convertToVector(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.convertToVector(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: you can increase the memory by specifying the jvmargs

Comment: 2 _million_ elements in the array?

Comment: Perhaps you're not aware that an array of size N always includes N object references.  When you don't set them, they will refer to null, but that is still a reference.  So you have (2 million * books.size()) object references just in the `data` array, plus your `books` collection.

Comment: If you really have that many entries, you should reconsider your whole design. Are you getting that data out of a database? If yes, process them on after another (or maybe in groups of 100), not all at once. Parsing some file? GO line by line/entry by entry. It's a bad idea to store such huge data at once in memory.

Comment: @fge sorry it's only 200000 elements only.. it's my mistake i edit question

Comment: **"only"**? That's still way too much!

Comment: Your design is broken. You're going to have to paginate your displayed results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second dimension of the array are the columns. You seem to be using 9 columns. So try:

```
Object[][] data = new Object[books.size()][9];
```